# TableView ExpandingCell with sectionHeader

Tags: ios, uitableview, expand

i have problem when i use expanding cell with section header
i use the cell update code which can insert the row and delete the row so this way i used to cell expanding but problem is i use the section header so when i try to click on expanded cell it crash where i am wrong please help me.

[image: normal cell]
[image: expending cell image]

```
    - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    BOOL preventReopen = NO;

    if (row == expandedRowIndex + 1 && expandedRowIndex != -1)
        return nil;

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if (expandedRowIndex != -1)
    {
        NSInteger rowToRemove = expandedRowIndex + 1;

        preventReopen = row == expandedRowIndex;
        if (row > expandedRowIndex)
            row--;
        expandedRowIndex = -1;
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToRemove inSection:indexpath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    NSInteger rowToAdd = -1;
    if (!preventReopen)
    {
        rowToAdd = row + 1;
        expandedRowIndex = row;
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToAdd inSection:indexpath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    }
    [tableView endUpdates];

    return nil;
```

Comment: What does the crash report say? Include the trace log and code of your `didSelectRowAtIndex:` also.